Clickhouse-driver Chunking
I use clickhouse-driver to create a pandas dataframe from an SQL query with the following command:
data = client.query_dataframe('CUSTOM SQL QUERY')

But I receive a memory error:

ServerException: Code: 241. DB::Exception: Memory limit (for query)
exceeded: would use 74.51 GiB (attempt to allocate chunk of 4531920
bytes), maximum: 74.51 GiB. OvercommitTracker decision: Memory
overcommit isn't used. OvercommitTracker isn't set.. Stack trace:

Is there a way to chunk a query? I haven't found a solution in the documentation.

Maybe https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#streaming-results?

Doesn't seem to work.

Do you get the same error? Are you able to execute the query successfully with clickhouse client on the same machine?

Yes, I am able to execute an analogous query on the same machine. As for the settings = {'max_block_size': 100000} \ rows_gen = client.execute_iter('custom sql query', settings=settings), I get the same error 'DB::Exception: Memory limit (for query) exceeded: would use 74.51 GiB (attempt to allocate chunk of 4511503 bytes), maximum: 74.51 GiB. OvercommitTracker decision: Memory overcommit isn't used. OvercommitTracker isn't set..'.

How about tuning the max_block_size to even smaller, say, 10000? Can you paste the full stack trace? And what's the total memory of your working machine?

Error is not related to clickhouse client library
Check your SQL query, if it contains GROUP BY and ORDER BY and sub-queries
try to tune
max_bytes_before_external_group_by
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/query-complexity#settings-max_bytes_before_external_group_by
and
max_bytes_before_external_sort
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/query-complexity#settings-max_bytes_before_external_sort
also look to
https://azat.sh/presentations/2022-know-your-clickhouse/#/40

Thank you for the idea. I solved my issue by splitting the querry on each cte, creating a number of standalone tables and merging them afterwards. When it is just select * from the final table.

Yes, the error wasn't related to the library - it occurred due to an efficiency of the SQL query. To resolve the issue I had to rewrite the query.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review
